# Superficial current on a magnetic cylinder / analogy with solenoid

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

On a cylinder subjected to a magnetic field is created a superficial current due to the movement of precession of the electrons. It is said to be analogous to a solenoid.

But for a solenoid the current is free whereas here it is linked, it does not seem to me the same at all. Plus, how many turns per unit length should this analog solenoid have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept of free and bound currents is artificial. It is just a convenient way used to calculate magnetic fields in materials. The bottom line is that the magnetic field $\boldsymbol{B}$ doesn't care whether a current is free or bound, only the total current density $\boldsymbol{J}$ at each point in space matters.

As for your second question, keep in mind that $\boldsymbol{J}$ is the fundamental quantity and not $I$. In the case of a solenoid, telling you $I$ and the turns density $n$ is just another way of saying $\boldsymbol{J}=nI\delta\left(r-R\right)\boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}}$. In other words, you can't distinguish between $I$ and $n$, as in all your equations they will show up together in the form $nI$.